# Добавление прокрутки к QML виджетам (Qt 5.9.3)

Tags: qt, прокрутка, qml, scrollview

Необходимо добавить прокрутку к `TextEdit` (вертикальную) и к `ListView` (горизонтальную); полосы прокрутки должны отображаться при необходимости. И `TextEdit`, и `ListView` должны заполнять всё, отведённое им родителями пространство. Примеры из справки не помогают.

`ScrollableTextEdit`:

```
ColumnLayout {
    ...
    ScrollView {
        id: scroll_view
        Layout.fillWidth: true // Возможно, ошибка здесь
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
        ???
        Rectangle {
            border.color: 'gray'
            ???
            TextEdit {
                id: text_edit
                anchors.fill: parent
                textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
                wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ScrollableListView`:

```
ColumnLayout {
    ...
    ScrollView {
        id: scroll_view
        Layout.fillWidth: true // Возможно, ошибка здесь
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff
        ???
        Rectangle {
            border.color: 'gray'
            ???
            ListView {
                id: list_view
                anchors.fill: parent
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```